# Trading model for breakout strategy

Tags: python, optimization, trading

I'm trying to build a model using historical price and volume data.

**Decision Variables**

The model should be able to decide:

1. When to enter a trade
2. What type of trade to enter (Long/Short)
3. How much SL and TP to keep for a trade
4. When to exit a trade

**Things to keep in mind**

1. The model should at no point take into consideration any future price or volume data when making a trading decision. E.g., a decision to enter trade should be purely made on the price or volume data from the past, it should have no influence of future. This is to simulate the real-world where future price or volume movements are not available anyway.
2. The model can use multiple validations to achieve the goals
3. Multiple time horizons can be looked at (e.g., 1-min candles, 2-min candles, 5-mins, etc.).

**Goals**

The overall targets to achieve through the model are:

Daily cumulative trading returns: >= 10% (cumulative = sum of all trades)

- Sharpe Ratio: >= 3.0
- Sortino Ratio: >= 5.0
- Profit Factor: >= 2.0
- Win Rate: >=75% (no. of positive trades / total trades)

**Approach 1 (using TA-Lib):**

```
import talib as ta
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
length = 14
k = 1.0
method = 'Atr'
show = False

# Data
# Replace [...] with your price and volume data
close = [...]
high = [...]
low = [...]
volume = [...]

# Calculate pivot highs and lows
ph = find_pivot_highs(high, length)
pl = find_pivot_lows(low, length)


def find_pivot_highs(data, length):
    pivot_highs = []
    for i in range(length, len(data) - length):
        if (
            data[i] > max(data[i - length : i])
            and data[i] > max(data[i + 1 : i + length + 1])
        ):
            pivot_highs.append(i)
    return pivot_highs


def find_pivot_lows(data, length):
    pivot_lows = []
    for i in range(length, len(data) - length):
        if (
            data[i] < min(data[i - length : i])
            and data[i] < min(data[i + 1 : i + length + 1])
        ):
            pivot_lows.append(i)
    return pivot_lows


# Calculate slope
def calculate_slope():
    if method == 'Atr':
        return ta.ATR(high, low, close, length) / length * k
    elif method == 'Stdev':
        return ta.STDDEV(src, length) / length * k
    elif method == 'Linreg':
        sma1 = ta.SMA(src * n, length)
        sma2 = ta.SMA(src, length)
        return math.fabs(sma1 - sma2 * ta.SMA(n, length)) / ta.VAR(n, length) / 2 * k


slope = calculate_slope()

slope_ph = [slope[i] if i in ph else slope_ph[i-1] for i in range(len(close))]
slope_pl = [slope[i] if i in pl else slope_pl[i-1] for i in range(len(close))]

upper = [ph[i] if i in ph else upper[i-1] - slope_ph[i] for i in range(len(close))]
lower = [pl[i] if i in pl else lower[i-1] + slope_pl[i] for i in range(len(close))]

# ----
single_upper = [0] * len(close)
single_lower = [0] * len(close)

for i in range(length, len(close)):
    if close[i] > upper[i-length]:
        single_upper[i] = 1
    elif i in ph:
        single_upper[i] = single_upper[i-1]

    if close[i] < lower[i-length]:
        single_lower[i] = 1
    elif i in pl:
        single_lower[i] = single_lower[i-1]

upper_breakout = [
    single_upper[i-1] and close[i] > upper[i] and (show or close[i] > close[i-length])
    for i in range(len(close))
]

lower_breakout = [
    single_lower[i-1] and close[i] < lower[i] and (show or close[i] < close[i-length])
    for i in range(len(close))
]

# Trading strategy
trades = []
trade_type = None
entry_price = None
stop_loss = None
take_profit = None

for i in range(len(close)):
    if trade_type is None:
        if upper_breakout[i]:
            trade_type = 'Long'
            entry_price = close[i]
            stop_loss = entry_price - 0.02 * entry_price  # Example stop loss calculation
            take_profit = entry_price + 0.03 * entry_price  # Example take profit calculation
        elif lower_breakout[i]:
            trade_type = 'Short'
            entry_price = close[i]
            stop_loss = entry_price + 0.02 * entry_price  # Example stop loss calculation
            take_profit = entry_price - 0.03 * entry_price  # Example take profit calculation
    else:
        if trade_type == 'Long':
            if close[i] <= stop_loss or close[i] >= take_profit:
                trades.append((entry_price, stop_loss, take_profit))
                trade_type = None
                entry_price = None
                stop_loss = None
                take_profit = None
        elif trade_type == 'Short':
            if close[i] >= stop_loss or close[i] <= take_profit:
                trades.append((entry_price, stop_loss, take_profit))
                trade_type = None
                entry_price = None
                stop_loss = None
                take_profit = None

# Calculate metrics
total_trades = len(trades)
positive_trades = sum(1 for t in trades if t[2] > t[0])
win_rate = positive_trades / total_trades if total_trades > 0 else 0

cumulative_returns = sum((t[2] - t[0]) / t[0] for t in trades)
sharpe_ratio = (cumulative_returns - 0.01) / (cumulative_returns.std() + 1e-9)
sortino_ratio = (cumulative_returns - 0.01) / (cumulative_returns[cumulative_returns < 0].std() + 1e-9)
profit_factor = sum(t[2] - t[0] for t in trades if t[2] > t[0]) / abs(sum(t[2] - t[0] for t in trades if t[2] < t[0]))

# Print metrics
print(f"Total Trades: {total_trades}")
print(f"Positive Trades: {positive_trades}")
print(f"Win Rate: {win_rate * 100}%")
print(f"Cumulative Returns: {cumulative_returns * 100}%")
print(f"Sharpe Ratio: {sharpe_ratio}")
print(f"Sortino Ratio: {sortino_ratio}")
print(f"Profit Factor: {profit_factor}")

# Plotting
plt.plot(close[length:], label='Closing Price')
plt.plot(upper[length:], label='Upper Trendline', color='#26a69a')
plt.plot(lower[length:], label='Lower Trendline', color='#ef5350')

for i in range(len(close)):
    if upper_breakout[i]:
        plt.scatter(i, close[i-length], marker='^', color='r', label='Upper Break')
    if lower_breakout[i]:
        plt.scatter(i, close[i-length], marker='v', color='g', label='Lower Break')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Approach 2 (using pandas_ta):**

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Load your price data into a pandas DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv('your_data.csv')
close = data['close']
high = data['high']
low = data['low']

length = 14
k = 1.0
method = 'Atr'
show = False

# Calculate the indicators using pandas-ta
data['atr'] = ta.atr(high, low, close, length)
data['stddev'] = ta.stddev(close, length)
data['sma1'] = ta.sma(close, length)
data['sma2'] = ta.sma(close, length)
data['var'] = ta.var(close, length)
data['n'] = data.index

data['slope'] = 0.0
data['slope'] = np.where(method == 'Atr', data['atr'] / length * k,
                         np.where(method == 'Stdev', data['stddev'] / length * k,
                                  np.where(method == 'Linreg', data['sma1'] - data['sma2'] * data['n'] / data['var'] / 2 * k)))
#data.loc[method == 'Atr', 'slope'] = data['atr'] / length * k
#data.loc[method == 'Stdev', 'slope'] = data['stddev'] / length * k
#data.loc[method == 'Linreg', 'slope'] = (data['sma1'] - data['sma2'] * data['n']) / data['var'] / 2 * k

# Find pivot highs and lows
data['ph'] = ta.pivot_high(high, length)
data['pl'] = ta.pivot_low(low, length)

data['slope_ph'] = data['slope'].where(data.index.isin(data['ph'])).ffill()
data['slope_pl'] = data['slope'].where(data.index.isin(data['pl'])).ffill()

data['upper'] = data['ph'].where(data.index.isin(data['ph'])).ffill() - data['slope_ph']
data['lower'] = data['pl'].where(data.index.isin(data['pl'])).ffill() + data['slope_pl']

# Determine trade entries and exits
data['trade_type'] = None
data['entry_price'] = None
data['stop_loss'] = None
data['take_profit'] = None

for i in range(length, len(data)):
    if data['close'][i] > data['upper'][i-length]:
        data['trade_type'][i] = 'Long'
        data['entry_price'][i] = data['close'][i]
        data['stop_loss'][i] = data['entry_price'][i] - 0.02 * data['entry_price'][i]
        data['take_profit'][i] = data['entry_price'][i] + 0.03 * data['entry_price'][i]
    elif data['close'][i] < data['lower'][i-length]:
        data['trade_type'][i] = 'Short'
        data['entry_price'][i] = data['close'][i]
        data['stop_loss'][i] = data['entry_price'][i] + 0.02 * data['entry_price'][i]
        data['take_profit'][i] = data['entry_price'][i] - 0.03 * data['entry_price'][i]

data['trade_type'] = data['trade_type'].ffill()
data['entry_price'] = data['entry_price'].ffill()
data['stop_loss'] = data['stop_loss'].ffill()
data['take_profit'] = data['take_profit'].ffill()

data['exit_trade'] = False
for i in range(length, len(data)):
    if (
        (data['trade_type'][i] == 'Long' and data['low'][i] < data['stop_loss'][i]) or
        (data['trade_type'][i] == 'Short' and data['high'][i] > data['stop_loss'][i])
    ):
        data['exit_trade'][i] = True

# Calculate trading metrics
total_trades = len(data[data['entry_price'].notnull()])
positive_trades = len(data[(data['entry_price'].notnull()) & (data['close'] > data['entry_price'])])
win_rate = positive_trades / total_trades if total_trades > 0 else 0.0

# Plotting
plt.plot(data['close'][length:], label='Closing Price')
plt.plot(data['upper'][length:], label='Upper Trendline', color='#26a69a')
plt.plot(data['lower'][length:], label='Lower Trendline', color='#ef5350')

for i in range(len(data)):
    if not pd.isnull(data['entry_price'][i]):
        if data['trade_type'][i] == 'Long':
            plt.scatter(i, data['entry_price'][i], marker='^', color='r', label='Long Entry')
        else:
            plt.scatter(i, data['entry_price'][i], marker='v', color='g', label='Short Entry')
    if data['exit_trade'][i]:
        plt.scatter(i, data['stop_loss'][i], marker='x', color='b', label='Exit')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I need suggestions about how to incorporate all the goals and make the code, more optimized and better.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pands-ta` the library is lighter and faster than `ta-lib`

Comment: Many thanks, I've added my approach with `pandas_ta`,  now can you please help me with added functionalities?